# Cocos2d-js: How to show console output of iPhone app in Xcode console (release version)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, logging, cocos2d-js

I think, I can only run cocos2d-js apps on the iPhone in release version. How can I get console output there? Normal cc.log() - Text is not displayed in the console of XCode.

How can I set the COCOS2D_DEBUG constant to 1 in release mode?

Answer (score 0):

you can set COCOS2D_DEBUG=1 in release mode, but you should not do this

if cocos2d_debug = 1 both in debug and release mode, why do you need this tag?

you can see logs in release mode from xcode menu-> window->organizer->device logs

Comment: I found out, that I can run the cocos2d app in debug mode on iPhone. But the cc.log output still doesn't appear in the device logs of the organizer. Other output is there. Just the cc.logs are missing. And that's just what I need.

Comment: On the console of my iPhone in the organizer I get some messages from my app like "Sep  9 09:45:35 iPhone-von-Michael-Schmidt 42words-js2 iOS[2625] <Warning>: Received memory warning." but the Device Logs section stays empty.

Comment: @Michael i'm sorry for the late reply, i find that cocos2d log will display in console in release mode, if you use cocos2d::log() instead of cclog(), because cclog is defined as blank function in release mode, but cocos2d::log() is not